# Difference between getItem and getSelectedItem

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

In working with the `JComboBox` in Swing and reading up all the interfaces and classes and their various properties, I am not confused between the `ComboBoxEditor`'s `getItem` method, and the `JComboBox`'s  `getSelectedItem`.

I am talking from the point of view of an editable combo box. When I call both these methods after editing some text in the combo box and pressing enter, both methods return the same value. Of course, that is expected, but then what are the specific uses of these two methods ? Is there any difference in the order in which they are called from within the combo box's code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ComboBoxEditor's [`getItem()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxEditor.html#getItem%28%29) of function returns the **edited** item
And JComboBox `getSelectedItem()` returns the selected item.  However to be specific to your question:

> Is there any difference in the order in which they are called from
>   within the combo box's code ?

An editable Combo Box uses an editor to display the selected item. As soon as an item is edited, an action event is fired on registered `ComboBoxEditor` instance of the `JComboBox` . The implemented `actionPerformed` function of editor's action listener, gets the  edited `item` from `editor` and then set as `selected` using the `model`'s `setSelectedItem(item)` function which is evident from the following source code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object newItem = getEditor().getItem(); // get edited's item
        setPopupVisible(false);
        getModel().setSelectedItem(newItem);   // model set the item as selected
        String oldCommand = getActionCommand();
        setActionCommand("comboBoxEdited");
        fireActionEvent();
        setActionCommand(oldCommand);
    }
```

Then, when we ask to get `getSelectedItem()` it returns the selected item by asking the `model`.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you ever want to use the ComboBoxEditor's getItem() method? It is extra work to get the editor in order to get its value.

In general you should only ever get the data from the components model. The model is responsible for tracking the data in the model as well as the selected item in the model. The getSelectedItem() method of the combobox is a convenience method to get the selected item from the model.

It is the editors responsibility to update the model when the data is changed. So I would say the getItem() method is used by the editor to update the model at the appropriate time and you should not really be using it.